# Using dplyr summarize and group_by functions based on "or" condition among multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I can measure the proportion of 1 instances in my x column in below df:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~x, 
  'A',0,
  'A',1,
  'A',1,
  'B',0,
  'B',0,
  'B',1,
  'C',1,
  'C',0,
  'C',0,
  'C',1,
)


df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    result = round(prop.table(table(x))["1"]*100, digits = 2)
    )

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  id    result
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A       66.7
2 B       33.3
3 C       50
```

But what I really want is to measure the proportion of instances of 1 if any of the x, y and z column have the value of 1. For instance, in below case for category A, row one has zero value since all x, y and z values are zero but row two and three has the value of 1 because at least 1 appeared in one the x, y and z column. Therefore, again category A has the 66.7% of 1 values with `group_by` and `summarize` function used above (2 out of three rows of A category have value of 1)

```
df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~x, ~y, ~z
  'A',0,0,0,
  'A',1,0,0,
  'A',1,1,0,
  'B',0,0,0,
  'B',0,0,0,
  'B',1,0,0,
  'C',1,0,0,
  'C',0,0,0,
  'C',0,0,0,
  'C',1,0,0,
)
```

Comment: Just FYI, a more standard way (and more efficient way) to calculate the proportion of `1`s than `prop.table(table(x))["1"]` is `mean(x == 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `mean` + `rowSums`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    result = mean(rowSums(across(x:z)) >= 1)
  )

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  id    result
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A      0.667
2 B      0.333
3 C      0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

We may use

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
   reframe(result = mean(if_any(x:z)), .by = id)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  id    result
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A      0.667
2 B      0.333
3 C      0.5
```

According to `?reframe`

> reframe() creates a new data frame by applying functions to columns of an existing data frame. It is most similar to summarise(), with two big differences:

> reframe() can return an arbitrary number of rows per group, while summarise() reduces each group down to a single row.

> reframe() always returns an ungrouped data frame, while summarise() might return a grouped or rowwise data frame, depending on the scenario.

> We expect that you'll use summarise() much more often than reframe(), but reframe() can be particularly helpful when you need to apply a complex function that doesn't return a single summary value.

Comment: nice use of `if_any`, but why reframe here? summarise seems to be better suited since one value will be returned for each group

Answer (score 2):

you can use `OR` in the a variable like `(x|y|z)`and calculate its mean.

you can also test the `sum >= 1`

I agree with Thomas and Maël `mean` is more elegant way to do this

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(result = round(mean(x|y|z), digits = 2))
```